# How to display JSON object items in list format using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

how do i pull the items AND prices from my JSON string?  I am only able to pull price...When I console.log it displays what i want, but when i do an innerHTML, it does not work.  Do I need a for loop?  Please help and thank you

```
<html>
<p id="demo">

</p>
<script>
    var myJSON = '{"menu": {"slice of pizza": "2.00", "toppings": {"pepperoni": ".25","meatballs": ".35", "mushrooms": ".40","olives": ".20"},"sides": {"potato salad": "1.25","hummus": "2.50","caesar salad": "3.50","garden salad": "2.25"},   "drinks": { "soda": {   "small": "1.95",  "medium": "2.20","large": "2.50" }, "juice": "2.00", "water": "1.25"}}}';
    var myObj = JSON.parse(myJSON);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.menu.toppings.pepperoni;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.menu.toppings;
    console.log(myObj.menu.toppings);

    /*for (var i; i< myObj.length; i++){
        console.log(i);
    };*/
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: List format? What do you mean?

Comment: @Ele: "List format" wasn't a good term...really i just want to know how i can get it to display on my page (not just in the console)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to stringify the object using the function `JSON.stringify(...)`.
- Use `innerText` instead to leverage a better format.

```js
var myJSON = '{"menu": {"slice of pizza": "2.00", "toppings": {"pepperoni": ".25","meatballs": ".35", "mushrooms": ".40","olives": ".20"},"sides": {"potato salad": "1.25","hummus": "2.50","caesar salad": "3.50","garden salad": "2.25"},   "drinks": { "soda": {   "small": "1.95",  "medium": "2.20","large": "2.50" }, "juice": "2.00", "water": "1.25"}}}';

var myObj = JSON.parse(myJSON);
document.getElementById("demo").innerText = JSON.stringify(myObj.menu.toppings.pepperoni, null, 2);
document.getElementById("demo").innerText += '\n\n' + JSON.stringify(myObj.menu.toppings, null, 2);
```

```html
<p id="demo">

</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd suggest you use `textContent`, not `innerHTML` for something like this.

Second, you're going to have to turn the object `myObj.menu.toppings` into a string, not just use it directly as an object. How you turn the object into a string depends on how you want it formatted.

Something quick and easy that would work (but probably isn't the formatting you want) is `JSON.stringify(myObj.menu.toppings)`.